# Coffeescript error "undefined is not a function" in hubot

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I'm making call to my django app that returns a JSON object and I'm using the following code to do so:

```
robot.hear /lunch for today/i, (res) ->
    robot.http("http://my_ip_address/show")
        .header('Accept', 'application/json')
        .get() (err, res, body) ->
            data = JSON.parse body
            res.send data.food
```

but it returns `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the console. What's wrong with this?

Comment: This line looks wrong -- .get() (err, res, body) ->

Comment: Removed the paranthesis and this error occured: `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at /home/cube26/hubot/scripts/server_actions.coffee:105:5, <js>:116:21
` where my line 105 is `data = JSON.parse body`

Comment: I meddled around a bit and found that the undefined error is occurring because of `res.send`. Any leads on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is should look like this:

```
module.exports= (robot) ->
  robot.hear /lunch for today/i, (msg) ->
    robot.http("http://my_ip_address/show")
      .header('Accept', 'application/json')
      .get() (err, res, body) ->
        console.log res.statusCode
        data = JSON.parse body
        msg.send data.food
```

I believe the reason it is failing is because you are using `res` in the place of `msg` and then `res` again in the context of the function `.get()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error is on this line:

```
.get() (err, res, body) ->
```

Instead of passing the callback as an argument to `get`, you're calling `get` with no arguments and then trying to call the result (which is `undefined`) as though it were a function. My CoffeeScript is rusty, but I think you want this instead:

```
.get (err, res, body) ->
```

Comment: Removed the paranthesis and this error occured: `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at /home/cube26/hubot/scripts/server_actions.coffee:105:5, <js>:116:21
` where my line 105 is `data = JSON.parse body`

Comment: you usually get that when you're trying to parse *undefined* as JSON. Debug through that function and see what you're getting back for your err, res, and body parameters.

Comment: I meddled around a bit and found that the undefined error is occurring because of `res.send`. Any leads on why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the server returning? Does `err` have a value?

Answer (score 0):

It might be incompatible version of installed hubot and documentation but I found out the res from an http method has no send, but the one from the /hear command does.

```
robot.hear /lunch for today/i, (res) ->
    robot.http("http://my_ip_address/show")
        .header('Accept', 'application/json')
        .get() (err, msg, body) ->
            data = JSON.parse body
            res.send data.food
```

This should work, but either the official documentation is wrong, either the default installation of hubot is outdated.